# How can I change the gridline color for the row?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I tried

```
IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
    @Override
    public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
        int rowIndex = bodyDataLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);
        if ( rowIndex == 2) {
            configLabels.addLabel("FOO");
        }
    }
};
bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
natTable.getConfigRegistry().registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.GRID_LINE_COLOR, GUIHelper.COLOR_GREEN, DisplayMode.NORMAL, "FOO");
```

but it didn't work out.
How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem, more description add to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change the grid line color of a single row. You can only change it for the whole grid. The only other way is to overpaint via IOverlayPainter.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.